# Adjusting my table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

Here is the code I wrote so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}
      
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{2}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}

 \newgeometry{top=1.75in, hmargin=1in ,bottom=1in} 
 \begin{center}
     ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
 \end{center}
 \vspace{1.5\baselineskip}
 
 
%\hspace{5pt}

\normalsize
\doublespacing
\setlength{\parindent}{.5 in}

\lipsum[1-2]\\



\vspace*{.5\baselineskip}\noindent\hspace{0.5\textwidth}Marwa A.S. Mosallam
\newpage
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
 \newgeometry{top=1.75in, hmargin=1in ,bottom=1in} 
 \begin{center}
     TABLE OF CONTENTS
 \end{center}
 \vspace{1.5\baselineskip}
 
  \newcommand{\page}[1]{\rightskip=25pt \dotfill\rlap{\hbox to 25pt{\hfill#1}}\par}
  \doublespacing
  ACKNOWLEDGEMENT ................................................ii\\
  LIST OF FIGURES ...............................................iii\\
  CHAPTER
  
\begin{itemize}
  \item[2.1] An example \page{21}
  \item[2.2] A longer example like this such that the line wraps down to the
    next line and the last entry gets wrapped to the next line \page{22}
  \item[2.31] Another example \page{132}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

But I am having very hard time adjusting the numbering beside the word ACHNOWLEDGMENT and LIST OF FIGURES to be exactly above the other numbers of items 2.1, 2.2 and so on.
Can anyone help me in adjusting this please?

**EDIT:**

At the end I mainly need my table of contents to look like this:

> [image]

Comment: Table of contact or 'table of contents'? and what do you mean by numbering acknowledgement and others? Like chapter numbering?

Comment: The `article` document class doesn't provide a **chapter**-level sectioning unit. Hence, the instruction `\thechapter` in your code is going to cause an error. Have you considered switching to a document class that does? E.g., `report`, `book`, `memoir`, etc?

Comment: @M.A.Bromuela this is what I mean by numbering the page of the ACKNOWLEDGMENT,  ACKNOWLEDGEMENT ................................................ii, in my document the ACKNOWLEDGMENT page is number ii. Also, in my document, the list of figures will be on pg. iii, this is why I am writing   
  LIST OF FIGURES ...............................................iii

Comment: No, I have not tried that, can you show me the details please? @Mico. My document contains other things that may depend on the document class `article`, but I will try your suggestion and see how that may require other changes.

Comment: If you are using the `book` class document, then putting ACKNOWLEDGEMENT, LISTS OF FIGURES, and  LIST OF TABLES in the `frontmatter` would allow them to have roman numerals in their page number where they are found.

Comment: All materials in the `frontmatter` are page-numbered in roman.

Comment: How can I do that? @M.A.Bromuela I do not know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}
    
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % For adding List of Tables and List of Figures to Table of Contents
    % Title cover page
    \title{Your book}
    \author{Your name}
    \date{}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \frontmatter %<-------------- Your preface, acknowledgement, table of contents and any prechapter materials goes here. Page numbered in roman numerals
    
    \chapter{Acknowledgements} % Your acknowledgements
    
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \chapter{Preface} % Your preface
    
    \lipsum[2]
    
    \tableofcontents % Your contents
    \listoftables
    \listoffigures
    
    \mainmatter %<--------- All your main chapters and contents goes here. Page numbered in arabic numerals
    
    \chapter{Chap 1}
    \lipsum[3]
    \section{Sec 1}
    \lipsum[4]
    \subsection{Subsec 1}
    \lipsum[5]
    
    \chapter{Chap 2}
    \lipsum[3]
    \section{Sec 1}
    \lipsum[4]
    \subsection{Subsec 1}
    \lipsum[5]
    
    \backmatter %<------------------------ Your appendices and other back matter contents here. Page number continued from mainmatter
    
    \appendix
    
    \chapter{Appendix A}
    
    \lipsum[6]
    \end{document}
```

**EDIT:**

In case you want leading dots following LoT, LoF and chapters you can use `tocloft` package in the preamble with `titles` as an option and then use `\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}` before `tableofcontents` command. So the full code now looks like:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % For adding List of Tables and List of Figures to Table of Contents
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

% Title cover page
\title{Your book}
\author{Your name}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\frontmatter %<-------------- Your preface, acknowledgement, table of contents and any prechapter materials goes here. Page numbered in roman numerals

\chapter{Acknowledgements} % Your acknowledgements

\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Preface} % Your preface

\lipsum[2]

\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\tableofcontents % Your contents
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\mainmatter %<--------- All your main chapters and contents goes here. Page numbered in arabic numerals

\chapter{Chap 1}
\lipsum[3]
\section{Sec 1}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{Subsec 1}
\lipsum[5]

\chapter{Chap 2}
\lipsum[3]
\section{Sec 1}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{Subsec 1}
\lipsum[5]

\backmatter %<------------------------ Your appendices and other back matter contents here. Page number continued from mainmatter

\appendix

\chapter{Appendix A}

\lipsum[6]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I have leading dots in front of the front matter also? Can the leading dots be closer to each other than this?

Comment: Yes you can. This apply to chapters equally. Updating in a minute.

Comment: Updated. You can now take a look at the edit. And in case you want to make list of tables (LoT) in uppercase you can go for `\renewcommand{\listtablenames}{LIST OF TABLES}` before `listoftables` command. Similarly for list of figures (LoF)

Comment: I will look thoroughly into it in a couple of hours ..... thank you very much!

Comment: Can the leading dots have smaller space between the dots than this?

Comment: Use `\renewcommand\cftdotsep{value}` before `\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}`. Replace `value` with the amount of spacing you like. The value must be numerical only with no units such as `cm`,`em` etc. Example: `\cftdotsep{2}`

Comment: may I ask why you need this "12pt, twoside" in the `documentclass{book}`?

Comment: Read this article and you will know better. https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Single_sided_and_double_sided_documents Putting `12pt` is optional. It just makes the default font size `12pt`. `10pt` is another valid font size parameter.